# Gang scheduling in RTOS over a multicore processor

Tags: algorithm, embedded, multicore, scheduler, rtos

I understand that Gang scheduling is a scheduling algorithm for parallel systems that schedules related threads or processes to run simultaneously on different processors. 
Gang scheduling is used so that if two or more threads or processes communicate with each other, they will all be ready to communicate at the same time.  However, how does a gang scheduling algorithm determine that the particular set of processes will be communicating among themselves and hence schedule related threads or processes to run simultaneously on different processors?

Comment: The nature and frequency of your questions makes me wonder if we are doing your homework (or even your PhD!).  Most of this question is a verbatim copy of the Wikipedia article on the subject.  Can we get some honesty here?

Comment: PS: The third paragraph in the Wikipedia article is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Gang scheduling is usually applied to a job, either by operating system default or because the job has been marked for gang scheduling. All tasks in the job are scheduled together without attempting to measure whether they all actively communicate.

The following paper has an introduction and some citations that may help you get background on gang scheduling:

Papazachos, Z.C.; Karatza, H.D.; , "Gang scheduling in a two-cluster system with critical sporadic jobs and migrations," Performance Evaluation of Computer & Telecommunication Systems, 2009. SPECTS 2009. International Symposium on , vol.41, no., pp.41-48, 13-16 July 2009
URL: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5224147&isnumber=5224098